# Why function's names change after compiling a shared library?

Tags: c++, c, linux, shared-libraries

lib.c contains:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void testFunction()
{
    printf("This is the testFunction from lib.so");
}
```

I compiled file with this command:

```
g++ -fPIC -shared lib.c -o lib.so
```

After I runned nm on lib.so I found that testFunction became _Z12testFunctionv. Why? I think this is a big problem when it comes to load functions with dlsym.

Answer (score 5):

You compiled a C program with the C++ compiler `g++` (and your small C code happens to be valid C++ code). So you observe some [name mangling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling). You should use `gcc` instead (it is part of the same compiler suite [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)....):

```
 gcc -Wall -g -O -fPIC -shared lib.c -o lib.so
```

<sup>(I strongly recommend compiling with `-Wall` to get all warnings, and with `-g` to get debug information; the optimize flag `-O` is optional -it could be `-O2` to optimize more- and might improve performance of the generated plugin)</sup>

If you want to use C++ with `dlopen` & `dlsym` be sure to read the [C++ dlopen mini-howto](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/pdf/C++-dlopen.pdf).

Don't forget to read documentation about [Invoking GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html)

If you want to avoid name mangling in genuine C++ code, declare your functions as `extern "C"`.

Comment: It does "work" with `g++` which has a different role: to compile C++ code, not C code. It just happens that your C code is also valid C++ code. If you have used `new` instead of `testFunction` as the name, your source code won't be valid C++ (but remains valid in C) because `new` is a C++ keyword.

Answer (score 2):

You need to research "C++ name mangling".

Argument types and more are encoded in the final name the compiler generates.

If you don't want this (for example if you want the function to be callable from a `C` context), then you should make it `extern "C"`.